# Fetch data from Json in react.js

Tags: javascript, json

So i have data like this

```
{
"copyright": "Copyright (c) 2014 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.",
"num_results": 44,
"results": [
    {
        "display_name": "Print & E-Book Fiction",
        "list_name": "Combined Print and E-Book Fiction",
        "list_name_encoded": "combined-print-and-e-book-fiction",
        "newest_published_date": "2014-12-14",
        "oldest_published_date": "2011-02-13",
        "updated": "WEEKLY"
    },
    {
        "display_name": "Print & E-Book Nonfiction",
        "list_name": "Combined Print and E-Book Nonfiction",
        "list_name_encoded": "combined-print-and-e-book-nonfiction",
        "newest_published_date": "2014-12-14",
        "oldest_published_date": "2011-02-13",
        "updated": "WEEKLY"
    },
    {
        "display_name": "Hardcover Fiction",
        "list_name": "Hardcover Fiction",
        "list_name_encoded": "hardcover-fiction",
        "newest_published_date": "2014-12-14",
        "oldest_published_date": "2008-06-08",
        "updated": "WEEKLY"
    },
```

I need to take the value of each display_name which are Print & E-book Fiction , Print & E-Book NonFiction and etc..

Can you suggest something to solve it?? THX

Answer (score -1):

it is very simple actually. I suppose you have stored this in a variable named for example data so you'd foreach this with simple for in loop like this

```
for (item in data.results){
  item = data.results[item];
  var foo = item.display_name;
  // here you can add your checks whether it contains your string or not
  // and do whatever you want to with the foo, there is your display_name
}
```

Good luck! Hope I helped

Comment: Whoever downwoted this answer, could he explain to me why?

Answer (score -1):

Use map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
var a={
"copyright": "Copyright (c) 2014 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.",
"num_results": 44,
"results": [
    {
        "display_name": "Print & E-Book Fiction",
        "list_name": "Combined Print and E-Book Fiction",
        "list_name_encoded": "combined-print-and-e-book-fiction",
        "newest_published_date": "2014-12-14",
        "oldest_published_date": "2011-02-13",
        "updated": "WEEKLY"
    },
    {
        "display_name": "Print & E-Book Nonfiction",
        "list_name": "Combined Print and E-Book Nonfiction",
        "list_name_encoded": "combined-print-and-e-book-nonfiction",
        "newest_published_date": "2014-12-14",
        "oldest_published_date": "2011-02-13",
        "updated": "WEEKLY"
    },
    {
        "display_name": "Hardcover Fiction",
        "list_name": "Hardcover Fiction",
        "list_name_encoded": "hardcover-fiction",
        "newest_published_date": "2014-12-14",
        "oldest_published_date": "2008-06-08",
        "updated": "WEEKLY"
    }]};

console.log(a);

var names = a.results.map(function(singleResult) {
  return singleResult['display_name']
});
console.log(names);  // ["Print & E-Book Fiction", "Print & E-Book Nonfiction", "Hardcover Fiction"]
```

a.results is an array which you iterate using function map. singleResult is current element(object in this case) with property 'display_name' that you want to return to your new array which I called names

Comment: thanks,but i store the data in other file which i name it all-names.json.. the thing is i am not allowed to edit the data.. this is the way I do

Comment: this.props.url.forEach(function(BOOK){
                        if(BOOK.display_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText)!=-1)
                        queryResult.push(BOOK);
                    });

Comment: I answered the question. Read the file data to variable. You can use JSON.parse(data) to build json object.